# configureStore not working with two reducers

Tags: react-redux

when both reducers are working separately but when i am combining them they are not working what could be the mistake
i am making an app to keep track of the icecream and the cakes both reducers are working fine separately but when i am combining both they are not working and are not showing the number of cakes and icecreams

````
    ```
    ``
    store.js:
    import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
    import cakeReducer from "./cake/cakeReducer";
    import iceCreamReducer from "./iceCream/iceCreamReducer";

    const store = configureStore({
    reducer: { cake: cakeReducer, iceCream: iceCreamReducer },
    });

    export default store;`

    `icecreamReducer:
    import { BUY_ICECREAM } from "./iceCreamTypes";

    const initialState = {
    numOfIceCreams: 20,
    };

    const iceCreamReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case BUY_ICECREAM:
        return {
            ...state,
            numOfIceCreams: state.numOfIceCreams - 1,
        };
        default:
        return state;
    }
    };

    export default iceCreamReducer; // Use the correct export name "iceCreamReducer"
    `

    ```
    icecream container:
    import React from "react";
    import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
    import { buyIceCream } from "./redux";

    function IceCreamContainer() {
    const numOfIceCreams = useSelector((state) => state.numOfIceCreams);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    return (
        <div>
        <h2>Number of IceCreams - {numOfIceCreams} </h2>
        <button onClick={() => dispatch(buyIceCream())}>Buy IceCreams</button>
        </div>
    );
    }

    export default IceCreamContainer;
    ```

    `cake container :
    import React from "react";
    import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
    import { buyCake } from "./redux";

    function HookCakeContainer() {
    const numOfCakes = useSelector((state) => state.numOfCakes);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    return (
        <div>
        <h2>Number of Cakes - {numOfCakes} </h2>
        <button onClick={() => dispatch(buyCake())}>Buy Cakes</button>
        </div>
    );
    }

    export default HookCakeContainer;

    `
    `cake reducer :
    import { BUY_CAKE } from "./cakeTypes";

    const initialState = {
    numOfCakes: 10,
    };

    const cakeReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case BUY_CAKE:
        return {
            ...state,
            numOfCakes: state.numOfCakes - 1,
        };
        default:
        return state;
    }
    };

    export default cakeReducer;
    `


    `store.js:
    import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
    import cakeReducer from "./cake/cakeReducer";
    import iceCreamReducer from "./iceCream/iceCreamReducer";

    const store = configureStore({
    reducer: { cake: cakeReducer, iceCream: iceCreamReducer },
    });

    export default store;``
    ```
````